# Epilepsy explained by computational neuroscience

Tags: neuroscience, bioinformatics

A few years ago, on my maths masters, I did a module in theoretical neuroscience. I was shown that the mathematical framework the course developed for neurons, with a small adjustment in the parameters, would produce spike trains similar to those observed during epileptic kindling. These parametric tweaks could be attributed to mutations in ion channel/receptor structures. This was one of the highlights of the course, and when I came to apply for a math/bio interdisciplinary doctoral program, I cited it as such in my personal statement.

Now the interview is fast approaching, and I'm pretty sure it's going to come up, but for the life of me I can't track down a reference. After four years out of the game, my memory is hazy at best.

As I recall, this had something to do with short term plasticity. Normal neurons' response to unrelentingly high frequency spike trains decayes over time, while pathological neurons' does not. *This may however be entirely wrong*.

**What is a reference for the model I describe above?** An introductory/educational treatement is prefered, but the original paper is fine.

Comment: To meet the [standards of SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/faq) please consider concentrating on asking a well-pointed question (not on personal story, urgency, ...).

Comment: I echo Piotr's sentiment, but is [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0013-9580.2003.12005.x/full) the article?  Lopes Da Silva is a leader in the field.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I don't think there is an inherent problem with adding a person flavour to a question, as long as the question is still clear. In this case it is a reference-request for a very specific result.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev Yes, as long as one does not need to read one's life story before the actual question. Personally I am irritated by 'questions' in which I need to search for the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, epileptic spiking can occur very easily in many neural modeling studies, and therefore one should be very careful in asserting the possibility of certain aspects of model as a cause for epileptic activity. One possibility, as you mentioned, is the lack of short-term depression which prevents long sustained firing. But again, a simple increase in the global excitatory coupling can also exhibit similar dynamics.

Good luck on your interview.